# What do the terms attractive and repulsive gravity mean in Einstein's GR?

Tags: general-relativity, forces, gravity, dark-energy, cosmological-constant

What does the jargon **repulsive gravity** mean in Einstein's GR or even **attractive gravity** in the same framework? The notions of attractive and/or repulsive only makes sense, or at least we are habituated with those concepts in case of a force or a potential, as in Coulomb's law of electrostatics. It is not obvious what would a repulsive or attractive gravity precisely mean in Einstein's GR. Does attractive (repulsive) gravity mean deceleration (acceleration) of the expansion of space?

Answer (score 0):

These are pop-sci terms. Relativists don't use them because they don't have precise definitions. The precise way to discuss this kind of thing is in terms of [energy conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_condition).

Comment: More notably, they are the tendency of geodesics to be focused or diverged by certain types of curvature, which is intimately related to the energy conditions satisfied by the local matter.